# How to analyze the differences between experimental and theoretical data.

Tags: physics, spectral-theory, spectra

I have around 5000 data points of theoretically computed and experimentally measured (via FTIR) K2 line positions(v (v", J''; v', J'). I divided the data into wn segments, so that I could analyze the theoretical and experimental energy differences along these segments. Apart from descriptive statistics, how could I effectively analyze the data?

Comment: Sorry I do not know much about physics, but am still curios. Does each theoretically computed data point correspond to an experimentally computed data point?

Comment: @Giacomo Yes.  Sometimes the theoretically computed signal is measured to be very weak, but the theoretical data points are derived partly from experiments anyway. But this is not a physics question. More so mathematical one, how could I compare two data sets, the differences between them apart from basic descriptive statistics?

Comment: What mathematical model should the data points obey? Also what do you mean by "descriptive statistics"? Do you mean error propagation, fitting data to an error distribution, etc?

Comment: @vb628 Well, I am not sure whether I understand you, but the theoretical data points are computed using potential energy curve. Now, I just mean very basic statistics, like variance, mean, median. How much the data points diverge from zero ( in case the theoretical and measured data points agree completely).